# Setting background color for SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I want to know is there a way to set background color for a SKLabelNode not font color. I'm looking for something like below mentioned code, which is available in ios apps.

```
     label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding the SKLabelNode as a child of a SKSpriteNode.

```
SKLabelNode *label = [[SKLabelNode alloc]initWithFontNamed:@"Helvetica"];
label.position = CGPointMake(0, -label.frame.size.height/2);

SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)];
background.position = CGPointMake(200, 100);

[background addChild:label];
[self addChild:background];
```

Comment: Now text is not shown in `SKLabelNode` and that particular area where I added `SKSpriteNode` is filled with its color.

Comment: Have you set the label.text and label.fontColor properties to ensure that it is visible?

Comment: Yes . It was all working fine before adding these line of codes. If i give `clearColor` to `SKSpriteNode` then nothing is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the SKLabelNode as a child of a SKSpriteNode works but it hides the text. So, I resolved this issue by setting the zPosition of background to a negative number. Here is the **swift 3** code:

```
var label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
label.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(-label.frame.size.height / 2))
var background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(label.frame.size.width), height:CGFloat(label.frame.size.height)))background.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(200), y: CGFloat(100))
background.zPosition = -1
label.addChild(background)
self.addChild(label)
```

Comment: alternative: add the sklabelnode as a child of the skspritenode. then the text won't be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

be sure to include the text value before calculating the background’ GCSize from the label node, else the values returned will be zero as it has no text to determine the size of the label.

..correct about layer issues